# Ansible combining a filter or predicate with dict2items?

Tags: ansible

I have a dictionary that is stored in yaml. I'm using dict2items to iterate over it to add the key/value pairs to a file. The dictionary is a big. Is there anyway to filter the result of dict2items based on a specific key?

I want to do something like

```
{{ mydict | dict2items | filter('foo|bar') }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"Filter the result of dict2items based on a specific key."*

A: Use `selectattr`. For example

```
{{ mydict|dict2items|selectattr('key', 'regex', '^(foo)|(bar)$')|list }}
```